# Can one download GMaps offline areas without signing in?

Tags: google-maps

Can one download GMaps offline areas without signing in?

[image]

Comment: No, but you can sign in, download the offline maps, then use them off-line although they do expire in 30 (?) days if I recall correctly. If you do not/can't sign into Google, then you will need to find a different Map/Navigation app.

Comment: @acejavelin thank you sounds good please feel free to convert your comment into an answer.

Comment: Yes like @acejavelin said its impossible without signin in but there are many apps offering offline maps like [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mapswithme.maps.pro&hl=en_US&gl=US&auao=false)  which i used before and recomend it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comment section, it is currently not possible to download GMaps offline areas without signing in.

---

Comments:

> - No, but you can sign in, download the offline maps, then use them off-line although they do expire in 30 (?) days if I recall correctly. If you do not/can't sign into Google, then you will need to find a different Map/Navigation app.[acejavelin](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/146132/acejavelin) [Apr 4 '17 at 13:34](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/172493/can-one-download-gmaps-offline-areas-without-signing-in?noredirect=1#comment221068_172493)
> - Yes like @acejavelin said its impossible without signin in but there are many apps offering offline maps like [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mapswithme.maps.pro&hl=en_US&gl=US&auao=false) which i used before and recomend it. [Silent](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/356941/silent) [1 min ago](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/172493/can-one-download-gmaps-offline-areas-without-signing-in?noredirect=1#comment327149_172493)